# What does "while a <> b" mean in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

In an assignment we are to use a specific algorithm to find the greatest common divisor in assembly, written in assembly.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
Input:a,b
Local: c
 While a <> b
     While a > b
         c = a - b
         a = c
     End While
     While b > a
         c = b - a
         b = c
     End While
End While
At this point, GCD(a,b)=a=b.
```

What does **a <> b** mean in the third line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In certain old languages, the `<>` operator meant "not equal" (you can see it as "less than or greater than").  The convention `!=` has largely taken over nowadays.

Comment: There are still some copycats.  For example, the `Coq` proof assistant is pretty new and uses that operator.  So my comment should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

<> is the inequality operator.